# make google map icon images smaller

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making a browser based mobile app that uses a javascript based google map. I had to reduce the size of all of my graphics and make them smaller when I used this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=yes, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

I'm fine with that and I should have used a viewport from the beginning, and I have been able to resize all of my graphics except for my marker images. No matter how I resize the image that I use for it, it still shows up the same size.

Here's the code:

```
var iconColor = "images/orangeCircle.png";
homemarker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location, icon: iconColor });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including a public URL for the marker image you are using (or a test marker image that exhibits the issue)?

Comment: the url is password protected and not for public consumption. What other code would you like me to provide? I'll provide it but I can't see any difference it would make. This is where the marker and it's properties are being set in my code. I'm hoping that this is a common problem that someone has run into before and that there is another step to resizing custom marker images than just resizing the image itself

Comment: As per your suggestion goecodezip, I at least went to the image url in the browser and checked it's properties, and it's showing that the image itself is still the same size. So somehow I guess I'm not overwriting the image. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I brought up the images url in the browser and checked it's properties and it was still the old size. Somehow, the new image was not overwriting the old upon save or there was confusion as to which image I was using to replace it. Went and made sure it was overwritten and went to image url and it's properties changed and the marker is smaller.